# how to use namespace system in c++ builder xe?

Tags: namespaces, system, c++builder, c++builder-xe

i mistakenly unistalled visual studio from my system and now i am stuck with c++ builder xe, i have a code that uses members of namespace System, like String type etc. i have tried to use the namespace by statement

using namespace System;

and

using namespace system;

but neither works. it gives no errors with the namespace but doesnot recogonize its members and declares String as an undefined symbol. i would like to know how can i use this namespace in my c++ builder xe?? thanks

Comment: Those are .NET namespaces; I don't think c++ builder supports .NET development.

Comment: The RTL in C++Builder has its own `System` namespace, where `System::String` is an alias for the `System::UnicodeString` class inXE. Make sure to enable VCL when creating the project, and that your source files have `#include <vcl.h>`before the `#pragma hdrstop` statement.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just re-install Visual Studio from your install CD's?

Comment: That has no effect on C++Builder.

Comment: But it does effect the first part of the question about accidentally removing Visual Studio.  It would also solve the problem completely to just reinstall VS again.

Comment: Reinstalling Visual Studio would not solve the compiler issue in C++Builder.  They are completely unrelated.

Comment: yea i like to work with c++ builder, visual studio is just too heavy on my i3 :(